# Distance between two vertices in a graph greater than n/2

Tags: graph-theory

If distance between two vertices in a graph is greater than n/2 then there exists a vertex whose removal would result in removal of all paths between those 2 vertices.

I've been trying to prove this for an hours without any progress

Comment: Delete $v$ and you are done.

Comment: What is $n$? The number of vertices in the graph?

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream What is $v$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213966/question-on-graph-connectivity?noredirect=1#comment2470273_1213966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the vertices be $u$ and $v$. We are told any $uv$ path contains more than half of the vertices in $G$. If we take two $uv$ paths they have a vertex in common. This means the maximum number of vertex-independent paths is $1$. By [Menger's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem#Vertex_connectivity) this number is equal to the size of the minimum vertex cut for $v$ and $w$.

Comment: "If we take two uv paths they have a vertex in common" Thanks, that was key for me.

Comment: Well yeah, although you need to use Menger strongy, because it isn't immediate that just because every pair of $uv$ paths intersect in a vertex it doesn't mean that ALL the $uv$ paths intersect in a vertex (Well, it does, but it isn't at all obvious). This is where Menger comes in.