# Question on Graph Connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

Now this question is on graph connectivity and I still can't get my head around these graph theory questions. Now we've been given an n-node graph which is represented by $G=(V,E)$ and two nodes $s$ and $t$ are in $V$, where all the paths between $s$ and $t$ are strictly greater than $n/2$. Show that a node $v$, not equal to $s$ or $t$, exists, removing which from $G$ would eliminate all $s-t$ paths.

And next we have to devise an algorithm with runtime $O(n + m)$, where $m$ is the number of edges, which can find such a node v.

Solution: Now I tired making diagrams to figure out what the Graph may look like. One observation I made was that the nodes $s$ and $t$ can't be in a cycle because then one of the paths from $s$ to $t$ won't be strictly greater than $n/2$. It's fairly obvious. Lets have a graph which is just a cycle. There would be $n$ nodes and $n$ edges. Hence one of the two paths would be shorter than $n/2$.

Hence there are two options:

1. There is only one path from $s$ to $t$ in which case we can just remove any node between those two.
2. In the other case there is one path from $s$ to $t$ and one path from either $s$ and $t$ to any vertex in the path from $s$ to $t$. Hence we get a cycle from $s$  or $t$ to that specific vertex $v$ back to $s$ or $t$. Hence we can remove that specific node between $s$ and $t$ to disconnect all the paths.

In that algorithm I though one can just walk from $s$ to $t$ and figure out the vertex with maximum degree and remove it.

Is my solution correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could say that the theoretical part and algorithm with quadratic running time are just easy, but a algorithm with linear time would be very challenging. Your argument seems not convincing, since in the second option, it can surely happen that those two paths don't form a cycle.

Comment: ^So can you help me out with the second part.

Comment: As I said, I still cannot figure out a linear time algorithm.

Comment: How would we do this in quadratic time? I may be able to figure it out from that.

Comment: The first part follows easily from Menger's Theorem. Do you have that available to use? If not, then the idea is that if there is no such cut vertex, then in fact there must be two internally disjoint paths from $s$ to $t$, which is impossible if both paths have length greater than $n/2$.

Comment: Yup, the theoretical part follows simply from Menger's, and since checking connectedness can be done by linear time (say DFS), we can for each vertex not equal $s,t$, delete it and check whether it is still connected.

Comment: I don't have Menger's Theorem available to use here. Can one of you write the answer here?

Comment: Actually, the proof of Menger's is not so long, say just begin from max-min flow and then some transformations. And I really think Menger's perfectly fits this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

We show by strong recurrence on $n$ the number of nodes that for every graph $G=(V,E)$ and two nodes $s$ and $t$ in $V$, where all the paths between $s$ and $t$ are strictly greater than $n/2$ there is a node $p$ that is on all paths from $s$ to $t$.

Base case $n=3$: Let $G=(\{s,t,p\},E)$ be such that all the paths between $s$ and $t$ are strictly greater than $3/2=1$ the only possibility for $E$ is that $E=\{(s,p),(p,t)\}$ and thus $p$ is on all paths from $s$ to $t$.

Similarly for $n=4$ we obtain that the only possible graph is the line hence the property is satisfied.

Assume that the property holds for every $k\leq n$. 
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $n+1$ nodes and $s$ and $t$ two nodes in $V$, such all the paths between $s$ and $t$ are strictly greater than $(n+1)/2$.

We distinguish two cases:

- either there is an unique node $p$ such that $(s,p)\in E$. We have thus that $p$ belongs to all the paths from $s$ to $t$
- There exists two node $s_1$ and $s_2$ such that $(s,s_1)\in E$ and $(s,s_2)\in E$. Consider the graph $G'=(V',E')$ obtained from $G$ by contracting the two edges i.e. $V'=V\setminus\{v_1,v_2\}$ and $E'= E\cap (V'\times V')\cup \{ (s,v)\mid (s_1,v)\in E,v\in V'\}\cup \{ (s,v)\mid (s_2,v)\in E,v\in V'\} $. Assume, by contradiction, that there is a path in $G'$ from $s$ to $t$ on length $l\leq (n-1)/2$ this path gives you a path in $G$ ( by expending the contracted edges) of length $l'\leq l+1 \leq (n-1)/2+1 = (n+1)/2$. Contradiction.

hence $G'$ have $n-1$ nodes and all the paths from $s$ to $t$ are strictly greater than $(n-1)/2$. Hence by hypothesis there exist a node $p\in V'$ that is on all path from $s$ to $t$. And by construction this node is also on all paths from $s$ to $t$ in $G$.

This proof also gives you for free an algorithm to find such node. Either there is an unique edge leaving $s$ and you have your node, or there are at least two edges leaving $s$: you contract two of them and start again.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

@wece

Small fix needed in your proof:

In your "case two" you are deleting two vertices from $V$ (I am assuming that you meant $s_1$ and $s_2$, not $v_1$, $v_2$) and then you are saying that $G'$ has $n-1$ nodes. If you are contracting one edge, say $AB$ to vertex $A$, then you are eliminating one node (namely, $B$) and transforming all the edges $BV$ to $AV$.

So: $n$ changes to $n-2$, and all the paths from $s$ to $t$ are now obviously longer than $(n-2)/2$ = $n/2$-1. Also -- edge $s_1s_2$, if it existed, needs to be eliminated upon contraction. Thankfully, it could not have been present in any shortest path from $s$ to $t$.